# How are forms used in an MVC framework?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, forms

i have been doing simple MVC tutorials for a while and i get the concept. But i am wondering, when a form is displayed in a view, how is the form processed? A code to check for form submission must be present in the view file, which doesn't really fit because view should just be for displaying output.

So when you have a form in a view file of an MVC framework, where should the code to check for form submission be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code to check for and validate the form submission should be in the controller or the model, depending upon the type of data received from the form and what you're doing with it. That's the point of MVC. View files should contain only the barest amount of logic necessary to display the page.

Comment: But what i'm asking is, where do you check for form submission? Like, the actual code(IF statement) that checks if the submit button was pressed. I am assuming this -must- be in the view.

Comment: @lyrae: Why must it be the view? Bear in mind that in MVC, the first file(s) to be loaded would be the Controller. In your case, the Controller may check for a form submission to tell it what Model to load, or the Controller might simply load the Model based on the URI, then the Model checks for form submission. Based on the results of the form data validation, either C or M may decide to load the form View again, or load a different View. These may or may not be in different View files.

Comment: Coles - because you need an IF statement to check if the form has been submitted. If inside the Controller or Model, it would be inside a method. How would such method be invoked, then?

Comment: @lyrae: Why can't you have an `if` statement inside a method? If the View is blindly being loaded without checking if it's required, that is *not* MVC, that is merely a template. Also, note that MVC does not necessarily require OOP.

Answer (score 4):

Of course this depends on the specific framework, but this is rather typical:

- form data is posted to a controller (like all requests)
- data validation rules are defined in the model
- the controller runs the data through the model for validation
- if successfully validated, the controller does whatever it's supposed to do
- if data is invalid, the controller pushes error messages for invalid fields to the view
- the view just displays the error messages

Comment: I thought the Model was just to get/submit data, no? ie, the Controller would cal the Model to query a database, and then work with the data. ?

Comment: This is quite a common view amongst developers using MVC - particularly in PHP. It's easy to forget good OOP principles when using MVC and just "stuff" your code into the controller since it defines a website "action". However, the controller should just be a 'middle-man' between models and views; request comes in, controller gives data to model, model returns desired output data, controller gives output data to view, view displays it. Search 'thin controller fat model' to find more discussions surrounding this.

Answer (score 3):

The form submission can be handle in controller. check [this](http://mathayi.wordpress.com/2009/01/19/mvc-architecture-in-php-development/)

Answer (score 1):

I think the most common approach would be the controller, since it is the controller that handles all input data (via $_POST, $_GET etc) and then ultimately decides which methods to call to handle that input, and which view to output.

Comment: Agreed. But the code that passes the form data to the Controller, is in the View, no?

Comment: No - the view simply writes the HTML. The PHP engine will handle getting the form data and storing it in $_GET/$_POST (depending on the method attribute of the form) and from there it's really up to the framework to decide how to handle it. Often, a framework will wrap this data in some sort of Request object (which often happens before your controller code is called). You could check for the form data in your controller as follows: `if (isset($_POST['myFormField'])) { /* form data has been posted */ }`

Comment: Yes. this is where i'm getting at. However, the snippet of code you provided above, would be inside a method in the controller, correct? This is exactly my question. I was thinking that that IF statement would go in the View (which it shouldn't, because i know the view is just for output - hence this question is being asked on SO). So now the question is, if that code is in a method inside the controller, what calls that method to check the form submission?

Comment: @lyrae Every single **request** goes through a cycle inside your framework, which is usually *Router/Dispatcher → Controller → (Model → Controller) → View*. (For example, see http://book.cakephp.org/view/898/A-Typical-CakePHP-Request) Whenever you "open" a page or post form data, it's a new **request**. Each request goes through the same MVC cycle. I suggest you just start playing around with an actual MVC framework to get a feel for it.